# Vidalia tray icon

Tags: vidalia

[image]

Hi,

how can I change this little icon? I couldn't find where they put them.

Im using 0.2.12 version on my gentoo box.

Comment: What do you mean by changing? Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: well, I think the default icon looks really bad and I want to replace it with a fresh flat design icon.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the source and do whatever modification you want. It's free (as in freedom) and open source.

But... Vidalia is dead and you shouldn't be using it and probably don't want be wasting time on that, unless you really wanna revamp and maintain the new version.

Stick with the Tor Browser.